# Unclosed files for the types '[io.rearealm.com_example_myapplication_UserRealmProxy]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing

Tags: java, android, realm

I am developing app but I have implemented realm but I am getting following errors from the build

> Unclosed files for the types
>   '[io.realm.com_example_myapplication_UserRealmProxy]'; these types
>   will not undergo annotation processing
>
> error: Field "icon" of type "android.graphics.Bitmap" is not
>   supported.

below User.Java model class

```
@RealmClass
public class User extends RealmObject implements IChatUser {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Bitmap icon;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, Bitmap icon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }


    @Override
    public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}

below realm implementation

Realm.init(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();

        User userModel =  realm.createObject(User.class);
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userModel);






        //Load saved messages
        loadMessages(realm);
```

> below app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> error: Field "icon" of type "android.graphics.Bitmap" is not supported.

You can only store Realm supported types in a model class. The list is here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types

In your case, you need to convert the Bitmap to a byte array and back in the getters and setters.